# Plotting solutions of differential equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a second order differential equation that I am trying to solve with MATLAB's `dsolve` command. Ideally, after obtaining the solution of x(t), I want to put it back in the equation to find out an implicit equation relating d<sup>2</sup>x/dt<sup>2</sup> and dx/dt. Finally, I want to plot a curve with d<sup>2</sup>x/dt<sup>2</sup> on y-axis and dx/dt on x-axis. I keep getting error about `fplot` not being vectorized and a blank plot. What am I missing?

```
syms x(t) a b
eqn = diff(x,t,2)-a*diff(x,t,1)*(exp(-x*b)-exp(-2*x*b))==0;
xSol(t)=dsolve(eqn)
dx(t) = diff(xSol(t))
d2x(t) = diff(xSol(t),2)
fplot(dx, d2x)
```

Here are the errors generated:

```
Error using fplot>singleFplot
Input must be a function or functions of a single variable.

Error in fplot>@(f1,f2)singleFplot(cax,{f1,f2},limits,extraOpts,args) (line 208)
        hObj = cellfun(@(f1,f2) singleFplot(cax,{f1,f2},limits,extraOpts,args),fn{1},fn{2},'UniformOutput',false);

Error in fplot>vectorizeFplot (line 208)
        hObj = cellfun(@(f1,f2) singleFplot(cax,{f1,f2},limits,extraOpts,args),fn{1},fn{2},'UniformOutput',false);

Error in fplot (line 166)
    hObj = vectorizeFplot(cax,fn,limits,extraOpts,args);

Error in DEmodeling (line 6)
fplot(dx, d2x)
```

Comment: Did you examine the values of `dx` and `d2x`, see what they contain? You’re assuming `dsolve` is successful, it might not be.